# Outlook 2010 VSTO Add-In Keep Current Tab Active

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, ribbon

I have a custom xml tab in Office 2010 (using VB.net) when I press a button on my tab it takes me to the desired contact folder but the Ribbon.ActivateTab code doesn't do anything (focus switches to Home tab). Here is the code below, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Public Sub GoToContacts_Click(control As Office.IRibbonControl)

   'code to take me to Contact folder

    ribbon.ActivateTab("MyTabId")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the tab is activated before the folder is switched...

Try to handle the [FolderSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865625.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Explorer class which is fired when the explorer goes to a new folder, either as a result of user action or through program code. And in the event handler call the `ActivateTab` method of the IRibbonUI interface.

Where did you get the id of the target tab? Does it belong to your add-in?

p.s. See [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691834(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean by handle the "FolderSwitch event of the Exploere class".  My addin has the custom made tab and within the xml it is called id = "MyTabId"

Comment: I have got three files: ribbon.vb, ribbon.xml and ThisAddIn.vb. Could you please elaborate where I need to add the code. Apologies for my ignorance, I am a beginner.

Comment: Your tab can be activated for a moment, but then the current folder is changed and current tab is set to a default one. So, I'd suggest handling any event which is fired right after the folder is changed.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, as the tab changes to my custom tab momentarily. However, when the folder is changed the tab goes back to the default "Home". What is the method to stop this event?

Comment: I tried adding a time delay:

'code to change to contact folder

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

End Sub

But all this seems to do is delay the time before which the folder is changed.